# How to show values of long and lat on a map?

Tags: r, projection

I have a file with a projection of `EPSG:3410` that I want simply to plot using R. As the projection is in meters, I have a problem with the lat and long values (axes).You can see on the map that instead of 90 -90 180 -180 there are other numbers.

the code to plot this map:

```
       con1 <- file("C:\\Users\\data.bin","rb")
       r = raster(y)
      extent(r) = extent(c(xmn=-17334194,xmx=17334194,ymn=-7356860,ymx=7310585))
      plot(r)
      plot(wbuf, add=TRUE)
```

- How I can replace those unusual values on the map with 90 -90 180 -180 (so no changes on the original file)
- How I can get rid of the space up and bottom of the map?

Comment: Those 'other numbers' are clearly *meters*, as they run around at -2e7 to 2e7, or ~40,000 km (the circumference of the Earth), and also the `a` and `b` units in your sample code (the radius of the Earth). One can safely assume that all has to do with the statement `+units=m`, so search its documentation for other units.

Comment: `par(pin=c(width, height)`

Comment: `par(pin=c(10, 5)` ,  `plot(r)`
Error in par(plt = bigplot) : 
  invalid value specified for graphical parameter "plt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some workarounds to avoid the white space and to add the axis labels. Since both maps are in metres, it's not easy to plot lat-lon labels.

```
library(raster) # for xmin, ymin etc.

# plot raster without axes and box
plot(r, asp=1, axes=F, box=F)

# add polygons
plot(wbuf, add=TRUE, axes=F)

# draw bounding box at raster limits 
rect(xmin(r), ymin(r), xmax(r), ymax(r))
```

To add lat-lon ticks, we need to convert from the EPSG:3410 (metres) projection to lat-lon (degrees). We can create dummy spatial points in latlon and convert those to 3410, then extract the converted coordinates to add the ticks

```
# y axis:
x = -180
y = seq(-90,90,30) # you can adapt this sequence if you want more or less labels
S <- SpatialPoints(cbind(x,y), proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
S2<- spTransform(S, CRS(" +proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371228 +b=6371228 +no_defs ")) 
axis(side = 2, pos=xmin(r), at = S2@coords[,'y'], lab=y, las=1)


# x axis
y = -90
x = seq(-180,180,30)
S <- SpatialPoints(cbind(x,y), proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
S2<- spTransform(S, CRS(" +proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371228 +b=6371228 +no_defs "))
axis(side = 1, pos=ymin(r), at = S2@coords[,'x'], lab=x)
```

Another option is to reproject the raster, so the maps are lat-lon (degrees):

```
# reproject and plot raster
r2 = projectRaster(r, crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
plot(r2, axes=F, box=F)

# there's an option to disable internal boundaries, which is nice
map(database = 'world', regions = '', interior = F, add=T)

# still have to add bounding box and axes
rect(xmin(r), ymin(r), xmax(r), ymax(r))
axis(1, pos = ymin(r2))
axis(2, pos= xmin(r2), las=1)
```

Comment: OK, I added the correct position for the x-axis, should work now.

Comment: Because you are looking at a projected map (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_equal-area_projection). The EPSG:3410 projection you are using compresses the bottom and top areas of the map.